# Use where clause with IN Operator instead of join

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I convert this `SQL` query from `join` to a subquery using the `IN` Operator. I was asked this question in an exam but I wasn't able to understand this clearly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_name
FROM categories c JOIN products p
ON c.category_id = p.category_id
ORDER BY category_name
```

an explanation of how it works will be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `IN`, the query becomes:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category_name
FROM categories c 
WHERE c.category_id IN 
(
    SELECT products.category_id 
    FROM products      
)
ORDER BY category_name
```

The `IN` operator is basically a shorthand for multiple `OR` conditions.
So, in this case, for each record of `categories`, the subquery selects the products `category_id`'s and checks if the `categories.category_id` is equal to any of the `products.category_id`'s . if it's then that record will be included within the resultset and if not then it will be excluded from the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the conversion, you probably do not need the `distinct`.  Presumably, in a table with categories, the names are already unique:

```
SELECT c.category_name
FROM categories c 
WHERE c.category_id IN (SELECT p.category_id FROM products p)
ORDER BY c.category_name
```